# NOT `column` IN (...) vs `column` NOT IN (...) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Usually, When I want to `Select all of records when column 'ID' NOT have any value in (1,2,3)`,
I will use the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

But today, I tried to use different query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE NOT (ID IN (1,2,3))
```

And surprisingly, to me, it works! Both SQL Server and Oracle databases (other `sql` maybe works (?)).

I'm wondering, which one should I use?

Comment: they both have the same  semantics and should perform the same but use the first one as that is how it is usually written

Comment: They are also both standard SQL and equally valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rewrite both queries to use more explicit logic:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3)
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE ID <> 1 AND ID <> 2 AND ID <> 3;
```

For the second query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE NOT (ID IN (1,2,3))
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE NOT (ID = 1 OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3)
```

By DeMorgan's law, the above becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE ID <> 1 AND ID <> 2 AND ID <> 3;
```

So, your two versions are actually logically equivalent.

Just as a refresher to DeMorgan's Laws:

```
NOT (p AND q) == NOT p OR NOT q
NOT (p OR q)  == NOT p AND NOT q
```

Comment: Would `ID NOT IN (1,2,3)` return anything if `id = null`? (I know its unlikely, just checking my understanding).

Comment: no but neither would the other variant as negating UNKNOWN gives UNKNOWN